# google charts You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView

Tags: google-visualization

the code below used to display a timeline chart  and it worked fine, but it does not any more.

Currently we get an error "You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView" but i can not see any obvious reason for that.

I have checked a similar question which suggested to clear the cache, but this did not work on my case.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}">
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartViewOne);

    function drawChartViewOne() {
        var container = document.getElementById('viewExampleOne');   
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Date' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

                dataTable.addRows([

        [ 'Submission Date', new Date('2007-08-02'), new Date('2007-08-03') ],
        [ 'Priority Date',  new Date('2007-08-02'), new Date('2007-09-03') ],
        [ 'Classification Version D.',  new Date('2008-08-02'), new Date('2008-08-03') ],
        [ 'Classification Action D.',  new Date('2008-08-02'), new Date('2008-08-03') ],
        [ 'Production Date',  new Date('2008-07-02'), new Date('2008-08-03') ],
        [ 'Provisional Approval D.',  new Date('2009-08-12'), new Date('2009-09-03') ],
        [ 'Related Publication D.',  new Date('2009-08-12'), new Date('2009-10-03') ],
        [ 'Publication Date',  new Date('2009-08-12'), new Date('2009-08-23') ]

        ]);



        var options = {
            height:400
        };
        chart.draw(dataTable,options);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I could not replicate this issue (http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/88x7w47b/).  The only problem I see is with your dates: string-to-date conversion is inconsistent across browsers and regions.  Browsers each read the strings differently and make different assumptions about how to interpret the strings based on user locale.  Some browsers read all strings in GMT, which will result in date shifts for your users (as javascript normally does not account for timezones in Date objects).